# Including header files when using systools:make_tar/2 for a single application

Tags: erlang

To include the header files into the tar, you can use the `{dirs, [include]}` option. But this will include **all** the header files for **all** the applications in the path. How can I tell systools to include the header files for a single application? Putting them into a separate folder and including that in the `dirs` option is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

What about `{path, ["my_app/include"]}`?